# Отправка файла и текста из формы на почту

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form

В JS есть переменная message в которой хранятся проверенные текстовые данные из почтовой формы.
и есть переменная file_data в которой как я понимаю храниться файл приложенный к письму.
и есть обработчик PHP.

```
<?php $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$headers  = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n';
$headers = 'From: Ваш сайт \r\n';
$admin_mail = 'Ваш почтовый адрес';
$subject = 'Письмо с Ваш сайт';
$message = $_POST['message'];
mail($admin_mail, $subject, $message, $headers);?>
```

Вопрос, как добавить этот файл или переменную file_data в ajax и php чтоб он тоже отправлялся на почту.

```
          var form_data = new FormData();
          file_data = $(nameform).find('input[type=file]').prop('files')[0];   
          form_data.append("file", file_data);

      $.ajax({
          url: '/send.php',
          type: 'post', 
          data: {message: message},
          success: function() {  
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

JS:

```
          var form_data = new FormData();
          file_data = $(nameform).find('input[type=file]').prop('files')[0];   
          form_data.append("file", file_data);
          form_data.append("message", message);

      $.ajax({
          url: '/send.php',
          type: 'post', 
          data: form_data,
          success: function() {  
          }
      });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $admin_mail = 'Ваш почтовый адрес';
    $subject = 'Письмо с Ваш сайт';

    $message        = $_POST["message"] //body of the email

    //Get uploaded file data using $_FILES array
    $tmp_name    = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // get the temporary file name of the file on the server
    $name        = $_FILES['file']['name'];  // get the name of the file
    $size        = $_FILES['file']['size'];  // get size of the file for size validation
    $type        = $_FILES['file']['type'];  // get type of the file
    $error       = $_FILES['file']['error']; // get the error (if any)
  
    //validate form field for attaching the file
    if($file_error > 0)
    {
        die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
    }
  
    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content
    $handle = fopen($tmp_name, "r");  // set the file handle only for reading the file
    $content = fread($handle, $size); // reading the file
    fclose($handle);                  // close upon completion
  
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
  
    $boundary = md5("random"); // define boundary with a md5 hashed value
  
    //header
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; // Defining the MIME version
    $headers .= "From:".$admin_mail."\r\n"; // Sender Email
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$admin_mail."\r\n"; // Email addrress to reach back
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n"; // Defining Content-Type
    $headers .= "boundary = $boundary\r\n"; //Defining the Boundary
          
    //plain text 
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 
          
    //attachment
    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
    $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= $encoded_content; // Attaching the encoded file with email
      
    mail($admin_mail, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

php взят отсюда https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-send-attachment-email/

Но я бы советовал использовать api для отправки почты или хотя бы какую то библиотеку, например https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: C data благодаря вам всё пошло, но вот с PHP беда, не прилетала даже текстовая часть, пришлось в аякс докинуть строки processData: false,  contentType: false, и я принимаю файл или как {name: "Varlogic N_51213.pdf", lastModified: 1620291503446, lastModifiedDate: Thu May 06 2021 11:58:23 GMT+0300 (Восточная Европа, летнее время), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 157939, …}     или как  Varlogic N_51213.pdf, но файл всё так же не перекидываеться

Comment: А с плагинами  PHP не хочу связываться потому что не хватит знаний совместить их с моим плагином. Это больше как хобби в свободное время, не успеваю учить языки после основной работы

Comment: @Михаил1 Я гляну в чем  там может быть проблема когда будет время, один момент. Вы уверены что вас есть SMTP? Функция mail без SMTP не работает. Попробуйте отравить email без доп. логики, если не работает то проблема в SMTP.

Comment: Тестировалось через SMTP на Open Server. При моём варианте PHP прилетает текст, но не файл. Также пробовал через переменную и вашу правку в JS функцию upload file, тоесть в Send.php через пост он попадает.

Comment: ещё ньюанс с ajax? добавил уставки: processData: false,
          contentType: false, после этого в коде php похожем на ваш стал долетать текст и пустой файл untitled.bin